# Powershell Set Content Replaced string

Tags: powershell

So, i need to save a string that was replaced on files.

I'm doing something wrong, but i`m not be able to figure it out, what!

My code:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\user\Documents -Recurse -Include "*.txt" -File |  Select-String  -Pattern \b192\.168\.10\.2\b , \b192\.168\.10\.11\b -AllMatches -List |  Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.2\b', "DEV" -and $_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL" | Set-Content $_}
```

And gives-me the following error:

```
   Set-Content : Could not open the alternate data stream '1:192.168.10.11' of the file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\result.txt'.
   At line:1 char:323
   + ... place '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL" | Set-Content $_}
   +                                                         
   + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\paulo....ents\result.txt:String) [Set-Content], FileNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  GetContentWriterFileNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

   Set-Content : Could not open the alternate data stream '1:192.168.10.11' of the file 
  'C:\Users\user\Documents\test.txt'
   At line:1 char:323 ... place '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL" | Set-Content $_}                                                             
   CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\user\test.txt:String) [Set-Content], FileNotFoundException
   FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterFileNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `ForEach-Object` block, `$_` will refer to the current match result as returned by `Select-String` - to get the file path, reference the `Path` property:

```bsh
... | ForEach-Object { ... |Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.Path}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-and` operator is used inside `if` tests like `if(this -and that)`.
You should change the double replace actions from

```
$_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.2\b', "DEV" -and $_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL"
```

into

```
$_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.2\b', "DEV" -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL"
```

Also, if I understand the question properly, you want to find all string replacements in the file, and to get all, you need to remove the `-List` switch from Select-String.

Next, as Mathias explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62498804/9898643), you need to use the `Path` property from the current match to get the file FullName.
However, if you pipe this through to Set-Content straight away, you will get an exception because the file then is in use and you cannot write to the same file.

Below creates a new file in the same path, with `_replacements` appended to the filename

```
# use '-Include' instead of '-Filter' if you need more file extensions to filter on
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Documents' -Recurse -Filter "*.txt" -File |  
Select-String  -Pattern '\b192\.168\.10\.2\b', '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b' -AllMatches |  
Foreach-Object { 
    $file = '{0}_replacements{1}' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Path),
                                     [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Path)
    $target = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.Path)) -ChildPath $file
    $_ -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.2\b', "DEV" -replace '\b192\.168\.10\.11\b', "QUAL"  | 
    Add-Content -Path $target 
}
```

This results in a file called 'C:\Users\user\Documents\test_replacements.txt'

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\test.txt:4:DEV
C:\Users\user\Documents\test.txt:7:QUAL
```

The original file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\test.txt' will not be altered.

Comment: Thanks once again, for you guys, Mathias and Theo. I understand all your explanations. But, there is something is escape on me. The  string result inside the files is C:\Users\puser\Documents\result.txt:5:QUAL, when the ideia is replace only the string 192.168.10.2 by DEV and 192.168.10.11 by Qual. So, if i find the 192.168.10.2 replace that ip for DEV string and the rest of document stay the something

Comment: @Paulo I think I have misunderstood the question then. I thought you wanted to figure out in what lines the replacement would need to go, not actually change the file by replacing ip addresses.

Comment: No problem Theo. Your help was very useful.